# Estimating the arrival rate for a Poissonian process

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-process

I have run into some difficulty in understanding how poissonian rates are estimated from experimental data.

Consider the following scenario. I stand at the side of the road and start counting the number of cars driving past at time $t=0$. $N$ cars pass me by at times $T_{1}, T_{2}, ..., T_{N}$ where $T_{i} < T_{i+1}$. I stop counting the cars at time $T_{stop}$.

I see a number of different methods for estimating the poissonian rate for this situation:

1. I divide the total time spent acquiring the data by the number of counts: $\lambda = N/T_{stop}$
2. I consider the moment I count the first car as the "meaningful" start of this experiment and **don't** include the first car in the rate estimation: $\lambda = (N-1)/(T_{stop}-T_{1})$
3. Building on the assumption in 2., I consider the time the final car passes as the "meaningful" end time for the experiment: $\lambda = (N-2)/(T_{N}-T_{1})$

Whilst a poissonian process is memoryless (an argument for method 1.), I believe that time intervals between consecutive poissonian events should be  exponentially distributed. If this is the case, then isn't the definition of the time interval as $[0, T_{stop}]$ rather arbitrary? I don't think the intervals $T_{1}$ and $T_{stop}-T_{N}$ are exponential - they are completely defined by when I start and stop my stop watch, **not** by the process I am trying to measure.

What is the correct estimate for this process's arrival rate?

Comment: The good news is that all methods should give similar answers if you measure long enough and observe enough cars. Intuitively, any method other than 1 is throwing information away. Nevertheless I can understand doing method 2 if you want to ensure you start in a consistent way. I would avoid method 3, I may type up a more detailed reason why.  Short reason: even if you have a perfect Poisson process of rate $\lambda$, conditioning on $X_N$ being the last inter-arrival time before $T_{stop}$ means that $X_N$ has a conditional distribution that is a bit skewed (not exp rate $\lambda$).

Comment: Note that methods 2-3 are ill-posed because we may measure only 0 or 1 cars during $[0,T_{stop}]$, so the times $T_1$ and $T_N$ you use there may not exist.